# How to add data in database magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

I just wanted to add data in the database from this page.
Wanted to add just two filed in a database table that I created so I want to know how can I add these data in table any reference or code appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   Mr
 * @package    Mr_Dukaaniatest
 * @author     jhondoe17@protonmail.com
 * @copyright  This file was generated by using Module Creator(http://code.vky.co.in/magento-2-module-creator/) provided by VKY <viky.031290@gmail.com>
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

namespace Mr\Dukaaniatest\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;

class Main extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, 
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,  
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig, 
        array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Item Information');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Item Information');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_mr_dukaaniatest_items');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('item_');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Item Information')]);
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('dukaaniatest_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'dukaaniatest_id']);
        }
        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'title', 'label' => __('Vendor 1'), 'title' => __('Vendor 1'), 'required' => true]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'author',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'author', 'label' => __('Vendor 2'), 'title' => __('Vendor 2'), 'required' => true]
        );


        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

this is the code of save page (controller)

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Mr/Dukaaniatest/Controller/Adminhtml/Items/Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Mr\Dukaaniatest\Controller\Adminhtml\Items;

class Save extends \Mr\Dukaaniatest\Controller\Adminhtml\Items
{
    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPostValue()) {
            try {
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Mr\Dukaaniatest\Model\Dukaaniatest');
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
                if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
                    try{
                        $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
                        $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                        $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
                        $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
                        $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
                        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead($this->directoryList::MEDIA);
                        $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mr/dukaaniatest');
                        $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
                        if (!$result) {
                            throw new LocalizedException(
                                __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                            );
                        }

                        $imagePath = 'mr/dukaaniatest'.$result['file'];
                        $data['image'] = $imagePath;
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    }
                }
                if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1) {
                    $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead($this->directoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
                    $file = $data['image']['value'];
                    $imgPath = $mediaDirectory.$file;
                    if ($this->_file->isExists($imgPath))  {
                        $this->_file->deleteFile($imgPath);
                    }
                    $data['image'] = NULL;
                }
                if (isset($data['image']['value'])){
                    $data['image'] = $data['image']['value'];
                }
                $inputFilter = new \Zend_Filter_Input(
                    [],
                    [],
                    $data
                );
                $data = $inputFilter->getUnescaped();
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                if ($id) {
                    $model->load($id);
                    if ($id != $model->getId()) {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The wrong item is specified.'));
                    }
                }
                $model->setData($data);
                $session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session');
                $session->setPageData($model->getData());
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the item.'));
                $session->setPageData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('mr_dukaaniatest/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('mr_dukaaniatest/*/');
                return;
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                if (!empty($id)) {
                    $this->_redirect('mr_dukaaniatest/*/edit', ['id' => $id]);
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('mr_dukaaniatest/*/new');
                }
                return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the item data. Please review the error log.')
                );
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setPageData($data);
                $this->_redirect('mr_dukaaniatest/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('mr_dukaaniatest/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you created controller?

Comment: yes i created controller but i want to add just these two fields in my table that i created can we add data from a current page in the table.

Comment: You need to create save class to save the data from your page. You will get those values in your controller then you need to create model for your table and save those

Comment: i updated my answer add save class please see

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i need to add these two fileds in my table that i created so i need to know how any code or refrence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83625/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-jhon-jhon-doe).